# PHP ID where $field is unknown

Tags: php

I am trying to display a pages ID which is created from a table field. Currently I have this setup

```
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
   {
   $Id = $_GET['id'];
   }
else
   {
   $Id = '147';
   }
```

This works great when I echo $Id
However the $Id needs to contain the text from a predetermined table field named $extra1. So I used the code

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
   {
   $Id = $_GET['id'];
   }
else
   {
   $Id = '$extra1';
   }
```

When I now echo $Id it simply says $extra1 - and not the actual content of that field. The field "extra1"will always be a 3 digit number and so when I echo $Id, it should display 222 for example

I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to do and look forward to any help

Thanks

Jason

Comment: Use a double quoted-string `$Id = "$extra1"` or no string at all `$Id = $extra1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $Id = (int) $_GET['id'];
} else {
   $Id = $extra1;
}
```

Or even faster:

```
$Id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : $extra1;
```

Comment: That is fantastic, appreciate it, thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

change it like this

```
      $extra1='123' //example 
      if (isset($_GET['id']))
      {
        $Id = $_GET['id'];
      }
      else
      {
        $Id = $extra1;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$Id = "$extra1";
```

OR

```
$Id = $extra1;
```

Comment: Fantastic, appreciate it, thank you for your time and help :)